# could not able to mount system ubi image through android init.rc

Tags: android, linux

I am new to this development. I am trying to port android on embest devkit. I have created ubi images for the Android root and system directory. I am trying to mount system ubi image in system directory of root while booting the board. For that, I have modified the `init.rc` and added the command to mount system.img:

```
mount ubifs ubi1:androidhome /system ro remount
```

Here, "androidhome" is name of the system.img ubi image.

But while booting the board, the process hangs at start of Android services:

```
init: reading config file
init: device init
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle' 
init: processing action 0x29a40 (init)
init: command 'sysclktz' r=0
init: cannot find '/bin/sh', disabling 'console'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sgx/rc.pvr', disabling 'pvr'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/vold', disabling 'vold'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/netd', disabling 'netd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/debuggerd', disabling 'debuggerd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/rild', disabling 'ril-daemon'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/app_process', disabling 'zygote'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/mediaserver', disabling 'media'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/dbus-daemon', disabling 'dbus'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/installd', disabling 'installd'
init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/keystore', disabling 'keystore'
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log, it seems the system partition is not properly mounted as expected.
But I found your are using "remount", have you already mounted /system?

Below is the example:

`mount ubifs ubi@system /system`

In the meantime, the source code of init should be modified too for ubifs, it could be very easily to found the patch from the internet.

Comment: Thanks, This issue is resolved. The problem of hanging the process due to incomplete /bin directory. I have created symlinks to all the requires utilities with busybox.  But again it was giving problem with mounting the system image. As you suggested, I had used "remount".  But when I tried only  "monut ubifs ubi@system /sytem", it successfully able mount system image.  Thanks again.